# Why can't I write to my array of structs in C in this way?

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I have an array of structs declared this way:

```
typedef struct {
    int a;
    int b;
} buffer_t;

buffer = (buffer_t *) calloc(SIZE, sizeof(buffer_t));
```

Later on in the code I write to it like this:

```
buffer_t temp = buffer[id];
temp.a = new_a;
temp.b = new_b;
```

But nothing seems to stick when I write to it that way. If I do this instead:

```
buffer[id].a = new_a;
buffer[id].b = new_b;
```

It works just fine.

What am I doing wrong here? Am I missing some vital part here?

(I have this code in my inner loop so I would like to make this as efficient as possible...)

I am using Visual C++ 2008 if that matters.

Comment: You've defined it as a struct.  I assume it has value semantics.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because `struct` values are copied: when you write

```
buffer_t temp = buffer[id];
```

`temp` gets a *copy* of the item at the index of `id`. You can modify the copy all you want, but unless you assign it back (e.g. `buffer[id] = temp`) the changes are not going to "stick".

Using a pointer fixes this issue:

```
buffer_t *temp = &buffer[id];
temp->a = new_a;
temp->b = new_b;
```

Now `temp` *points* to the `struct` at `buffer[id]`, so all modifications happen on the `struct` itself, not on its copy.

Comment: I don't know how I could have overlooked that vital detail. Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

When you create the temp variable, you are *copying* the struct, not creating a reference to it. If you want to make the variables modify each other, you can use a reference:

```
buffer_t &temp = buffer[id];
temp.a = new_a
temp.b = new_b
```

Comment: C doesn't have references. C++ does. This is C, not C++.

Comment: @icktoofay: It's true that C doesn't have references, but the person asking the question was apparently *expecting* the declaration of `temp` to create one.  The suggested solution should be adjusted to use a C pointer as you note, but mentioning that the original code is *not* creating a "reference" is good.

Comment: @supercat: Sure, saying the original code is not creating a reference is good, but the suggested solution won't work with C.